# Drupal 7: Display custom content type by custom method

Tags: drupal

Hi to all i have a content type named as "clients" i want to display them by custom method to manage their display like to manage display of thumbnail, title, content, and other custom fields on required places to keep look of design.
is there anyway to display custom content type data/listing by some php loop and access its title, content and custom fields to show them on my own choice instead of raw listing of items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some experience theming, and you need to do more than the "manage display" tab lets you, then you could create a custom theme that will apply just to the content type you specify.

You'll want to create a template: `node-[type].tpl.php` where [type] is your content type.  Check out node.tpl.php to get a feel for how it works.

Here's some info on theming nodes:  https://drupal.org/node/17565

This will give you total control but also requires knowing or learning how to theme (which you could get started with here: https://drupal.org/documentation/theme).

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing it one as @kayakdave as said, however if you are not comfortable with it you can use

Drupal 7 module Display Suit https://drupal.org/project/DS

You can check the DS resources here https://drupal.org/node/1857540

You can also use views and panels modules to create the layout as you wish.